# Document Management System for Health Clinic

Tags: document-management, workflow, health, process-control

I am the executive director of a small 501c3 nonprofit veteran's care clinic.  Because we are staffed primarily by volunteers, which rotate, I need a more streamlined approach for process documentation than our current approach of a Word document in a hard copy binder. I am looking for something that can be used in our small environment of about 10 users that will enable scalability and growth for future clinics, so cloud-based would be ideal.

Specifically, I would like a way to:

1. document processes
2. revision controls
3. include process flows
4. generate a training outline

Comment: Any price or does it need to be free? Does it need to have an web based portal? Could you briefly expand on your specific requirements?

Comment: You can give a try to Alfresco Community.

Comment: Could you please detail what you mean by "document processes"? Does it mean "Write some documentation about the organization's processes" or "Processes related to documents"?

Comment: What should the software do to help you "generate a training outline"? You will still have to type the training's content manually I guess, no software can invent it for you. What input will be used to generate what output? Should the "training outline" be a Word document, a web page, a wiki page, etc?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at [GNU Med](http://wiki.gnumed.de/bin/view/Gnumed/WebHome) which offers the following:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Runs on multiple platforms (including Linux)
- Available in multiple languages
- Maintains Client/Patient records securely
- All changes to records are recorded with time/date/operator.